# Remove duplicate based on text versioning

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text

Here's my data, I want to filter on latest version

```
Id       Score     Version
1           67     One
1           89     Three
2           78     Two
2           70     One
```

Here's what I want, because `Three` > `Two` > `One`

```
Id       Score     Version
1           89     Three
2           78     Two
```

What I did is

```
versions = data.scorecard_version.str.extract('(One|Two|Three)', expand = False)
dummies = pd.get_dummies(versions)
df = pd.concat([df,dummies],axis = 1)
df['versions'] = df['One']*1 + df['Two']*2 + df['Three']*3
```

And then filter max, but I am seeking for better solution

Comment: Is one, two and three the only versions you have?

Comment: A lot more, but this just simplified version

Comment: How do you expect my code to be able to understand the ordering of text that you don't provide?

Comment: Just use that three, let me generalize on my case, I'm also still trying, I give what I did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map you values, sorting and then drop duplicates:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,67,'one'], [1, 89, 'three'],
               [2, 78,  'two'], [2, 70, 'one']], columns = ['Id', 'Score', 'Version' ])    
d = {'one':1,'two':2, 'three':3}
df['vers'] = df['Version'].map(d)
df = df.sort_values('vers', ascending=False).drop_duplicates('Id').sort_index()
```

Output:

```
   Id  Score Version  vers
1   1     89   three     3
2   2     78     two     2
```

Comment: I was did this in way previous project, just forget where's the code